# Why wont my wolves eat the deer - NETLOGO

Tags: model, netlogo

So im writing a model for wolves and I'm trying to copy the code from the wolf sheep predation model

```
to eat ; wolf procedure
  let kill one-of prey-here                    ; grab a random sheep
  if kill != nobody  [                          ; did we get one?  if so,
    ask kill [ die ]                            ; kill it, and...
    set energy energy + 2     ; get energy from eating
  ]
end
```

however when I put this in my model and edit it so that the variables are defined, all of the prey species immediately disappear as soon as i press go.

Anybody have any idea how to fix this? 
or to add a working eat/hunt command?

also, is there a way i can add a factor, so there is an element of chance if they catch the prey or not.

thanks!

Comment: NetLogo is a modular language. That procedures looks fine to me and the description of your problem sounds like all the prey are being killed, which is what this procedure does. Therefore, the problem is likely to be in the procedure that calls this one. Please show us the code that does something like `ask wolves [eat]`. On your second question, please read the Stack Overflow guidance, you should only be asking one thing in each question. This question also doesn't satisfy the minimum working example requirements.

Comment: You might try adding some `print` statements to your code so that it explains what it's doing as it goes — this is often useful for tracking down unexpected behavior.

Comment: It may also be as simple as having your view mode set to continuous- with few agents present the model may run so quickly that your wolves "instantly" eat your deer.